# Full screen background doesn't allow for scrolling

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

I have a full screen background that is working when the window is resized but it's stopped the ability to scroll when a page is longer than the window. It just cuts it off.

How can I keep the full screen background but allow the user to scroll when on a larger page?

This is the website I'm working on - http://www.uktinplate.com/v1/sales/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add `position: fixed` to the background image element.

Then you need to take `position: fixed` off of `mainContent` and replace it with `position: absolute`

Then take the `overflow: hidden` style off of the `wrapper` element

Answer (score 1):

Set the image as a background instead of an actual image.

Then use the background-attachment property

[W3C Background attachment guide](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-attachment.asp)

Comment: The image is actually resizing when you make the browser window bigger/smaller. If I used background-attachment wouldn't it just stretch it to fill the window and be out of ratio?

Comment: Using CSS3 you can use background-size if that's what you're trying to achieve http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/

Comment: Would've loved to use CSS3 but browser compatibility issues, fixed now, thanks anyways.